# In ActionScript (NaN==parseFloat(input.text)) warns that it will always be false. Why?

Tags: actionscript-3, nan

Despite the rather clear [documentation](http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/action_scripts/actionscript_dictionary/actionscript_dictionary620.html) which says that [parseFloat()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/package.html#parseFloat()) can return NaN as a value, when I write a block like:

```
if ( NaN == parseFloat(input.text) ) {
  errorMessage.text = "Please enter a number."
}
```

I am warned that the comparison will always be false. And testing shows the warning to be correct.

Where is the corrected documentation, and how can I write this to work with AS3?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Because comparing anything to NaN is always false. Use isNaN() instead.

Comment: So even: if (NaN==NaN) { /* unreachable */ }

Answer (score 5):

isNaN(parseFloat(input.text))

Answer (score 2):

BTW, if for some reason you don't have access to isNaN(), the traditional method is to compare the number to itself:

```
if( number != number )
{
    //Is NaN 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Documentation can be found in the Adobe Flex Language Reference [Here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/2/langref/package.html#isNaN()) as well as other globally available functions.